# Deploy Heroku app with package that is not available in pip

Tags: django, heroku, pip

I am trying to deploy a new version of my Django application to Heroku, but I am using a package that is not available in pip. So when I put this package in the requirements.txt the deploy fails with the message that this requirement cannot be found by pip (logically).

Then I tried to push the directory containing the package to the heroku git repo and istalled the package using the heroku bash and the setup.py file (and removed it from the requirements file). This installation was successful, but when I deploy the application I get the error that this package cannot be found.

**So my question is: How to properly use python packages not available in pip on Heroku?**

Comment: What kind of package? If it's an app, just extract the package into your project directory (like any other app you may create) and that's it. It should be the exact same thing as creating your own app and registering it into `INSTALLED_APPS`. I can't see the difference.

Comment: Of course, how could I get forget about INSTALLED_APPS. Thanks a lot!